# Angular and radio buttons - Hide div based on selection and output value to other component

Tags: angular, radio-button, output

I'll try to go straight to the point. I have a Component whose HTML contains two radio buttons, like so:

```
<div class="row" id="existingFlows">
  <div class="col">
    <p>I dati personali sono trasferiti all'estero?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-lg-3">
    <div ngbRadioGroup name="existingFlowsRadio">
      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-success">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" (click)="setExistingFlows(true)" [value]="true"> Si
      </label>
      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-danger">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" (click)="setExistingFlows(false)" [value]="false"> No
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The value selected must be available in another component, so I had to use the output decorator, like so:

```
@Output() existingFlows = new EventEmitter <boolean>();
```

Now, I'd like another div to be hidden or displayed based on the above radio buttons selected value. Problem is that I can no longer use the "existingFlows" with something like

```
<div [hidden]="!existingFlows">
```

since the variable is no longer a pure boolean.

I would easily create another boolean variable and set it to true/false based on the selected radio button but the approach doesn't look good to me and I have the feeling I'm doing something wrong...

Do you guys have any suggestion in how to best accomplish this?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Since you used @Output, it seems that you are using parent/child kind of relationship. So you have to emit the event from child component and catch the same in parent component. You can emit the event on change of radio button value.

Coming to your piece of code:

```
<div [hidden]="!existingFlows">
```

As existingFlows is EventEmitter, it can not be used like ordinary variable and you will have to use another boolean variable to Show/Hide Div. You can use *ngIf directive to Show/Hide Div.

Here is an working code:
Parent component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <child-comp (eventFromChild)="someFunction($event)"></child-comp>
      <div *ngIf="showOrHideDiv">
        This Div is in Parent Component
      </div>
      `
})

export class AppComponent  {
  showOrHideDiv: boolean = false;
  someFunction(event){
    this.showOrHideDiv = event;
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
      <div name="existingFlowsRadio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" (change)="setExistingFlows(true)" [value]="true"> Si
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" (change)="setExistingFlows(false)" [value]="false"> No
      </label>
    </div>
  `
})

export class ChildComponent  {
  @Output() eventFromChild: EventEmitter<boolean>= new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  setExistingFlows(v){
    this.eventFromChild.emit(v);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ChildComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's a link for more reference:
[EventEmitter in Angular](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2)

Hope this help :)